# Php curl result in JSON get values

Tags: php, json, variables, curl

following is my code for php curl where i get values of currency conversion.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=USD_PKR&compact=y" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$response = curl_exec( $ch );
$json = json_decode($response, true);
print_r($json);
```

it gives me result

```
Array ( [USD_PKR] => Array ( [val] => 131.1098 ) )
```

I want to put **131.1098** into a variable where I will update a sql table query.
Kindly advice

Comment: RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: You know how to use curl, know json_decode, but can't access values of a simple array?

Comment: man these scripts are taken from different resources... if i show you the final code which i have made... you will understand my skills...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$number = $json['USD_PKR']['val'];
```

Comment: This gave me right result...

Comment: A big thanks to sietse85.. thanks

Comment: can you accept the answer ;) i also wonder which one downvoted it lol